# to show $f$ is real valued on $U\cap\mathbb{R}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Could any one tell me how to solve this one?

$U$ be open connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$ such that $z\in U\Rightarrow\bar{z}\in U$. Let $f$ be holomorphic function on $U$, if $f$ is real valued on a non de-generate sub interval of $U\cap\mathbb{R}$, then we need to show $f$ is real valued on $U\cap\mathbb{R}$

I got this question as a past years quals, I dont kow what is non de generate sub interval.

Comment: A non degenerate interval is an interval $(a,b)$ (open or closed on each side) such that $a\lt b$. // About the other question in your post ("how to solve this one?"), please indicate your thoughts.

Comment: Sure I will... Thank yuo

Comment: Please have a look at identity theorem

Comment: I am not getting how to start, please  give me some hints. how to apply identity theorem?

Comment: @Did May I interest you in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427265/polya-and-szego-part-i-ch-4-174)?

Answer (score 2):

With problems that involve reflection (such as $r(z)=  \bar z$), it helps to remember how to reflect holomorphic functions: $r\circ f\circ r$ is the reflection of $f$. Here, the reflection of $f$ is  $\overline{f(\bar z)}$, which is holomorphic in $U$ (check this). If you are still stuck, see below.

> Since $f(z)=\overline{f(\bar z)}$ on a set with a limit point in $U$, it follows (by the identity theorem) that $f(z)=\overline{f(\bar z)}$ for all $z\in U$. The statement about $z\in U\cap \mathbb R$ follows at once.