# Differentiability only in isolated point

Tags: derivatives

Do functions exist, which are differentiable in a point, but not in a neighborhood of this point?

Is $e^{\frac{1}{W(x)-2}}$, where W is the [Weierstrass function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function),  maybe an example of a such function?

Comment: I think $x^2$ times the Dirichlet function D(x) has this property at x=0

Comment: I finally remembered this old math joke your name alludes to: what's yellow, normed, and complete?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we multiply the Weierstrass function by $x^2$, we get a function which is continuous everywhere, and differentiable at $0$ but nowhere else.

Comment: Thanks for all responses. I set this answer as my accepted answer because I was looking for a continuous function. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 8):

The function $$f(x)=\chi_{\Bbb Q}(x)\cdot x^2$$ is differentiable (and continuous) only at $x=0$.

Comment: Simplified your example. Please revert if you disagree.

Comment: @Did I don't. In fact, what I wrote before was unnecessary.

Comment: @Did [Could you shed some light - if possible - on robjohn's counterexample in the comments?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427265/polya-and-szego-part-i-ch-4-174)

Comment: The solution in the book jumps from [$(v_n)$ converges to $v$] to [$f(v)=v$]. This step only holds if $f$ is continuous (at $v$). Hence, either the assumption that $f$ is continuous is in the book, or it was forgotten.

Comment: Oh, and +1 for the solution here.

Comment: @Did Ah, thank you on both things, but I'm capped!